# How to add rule in openerp7

Tags: security, odoo, openerp-7, rule, access-rights

I have code that shows I have multiple stations each station have a different worker.. I use rule to show each station to it's worker only .. I have supervisor who must see all stations .. how can I do rule for the supervisor to see all stations

This is rule for worker

```
  <record model="ir.rule" id="station_worker_rule">
    <field name="name">station worker Rule</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_mrp_production_workcenter_line"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id)]</field>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_worker'))]"/>
    <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the supervisor you have to change a domain and groups.

You have to put a domain

```
<field name="domain_force">[(1 ,'=', 1)] </field>

<field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_supervisor'))]"/>
```